# Importing Custom Blocks in Scratch/BYOB/SNAP

Tags: mit-scratch

I have created a bunch of custom blocks in SNAP/BYOB Editor and now want to share them.

I cant seem to find any ready references to this, is there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Snap lets you export global custom blocks from the project menu's entry named "export blocks". That opens a dialog box letting you select which blocks to export as a library. If you're unsure about dependencies among blocks export all of them (default). Libraries are saved to your download folder in an xml format. You can import blocks libraries into other projects either via the project menu's "import" item, or simply by dragging the library (xml) file into the browser with the target project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Jens! Or, you know, congratulations on your first post.